# How do I configure docker ports?

Tags: python, c#, docker, port, centos7

I have a C# program which reads a TCP stream from port 19777. It runs under docker, and has this in its yml file:

```
ports:
- 19777:19777`
```

Now I want a python program to intercept this stream, process, it and then send it to the C# program. I have tried a (run external to docker) python socket program which writes to a different port, 19888.

```
host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 19888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    print('\nListening for a client at',host , port)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('\nConnected by', addr)
```

To test it I got a Python program to connect to this fine.

I then changed the C# and yml to use 19888, but I get:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:19888: bind: address already in use
```

It seems to me that a solution might be to run the python server in docker but I am not sure whether this would work and how to configure the ports.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try running this; close Docker down first `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=19888 numberofports=1`. I had this same exact issue after the latest update of Docker. To check if something may be using it, run this: `netstat -ano`

Comment: It seems that another program already uses port 19888, check it.

Comment: Ah I thought it was the python server that was using 19888 that was causing its problem. I'm a newbie re networking. Thanks I will check in morning UK time, no access tonight.

Comment: OK so it is CentOS not Win. If I do `sudo lsof -i:19888` I get `...44u  IPv4  47184      0t0  TCP *:19888 (LISTEN)` which I think is the python server. I will try and translate the netsh command.